# concept of this in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 function Tour(el) {
    var tour = this;
    this.el = el;
    this.fetchPhotos = function() { 
    $.ajax('/photos.html', {
       data: {location: tour.el.data('location')},
       context: tour,
       success: function(response) {
          console.log(this===tour);
          this.el.find('.photos').html(response).fadeIn();
       },
       error: function() {
         this.el.find('.photos').html('<li>There was a problem fetching  the latest photos. Please try again.</li>');
       },
       timeout: 3000,
       beforeSend: function() {
          this.el.addClass('is-fetching');
       },
       complete: function() {
          this.el.removeClass('is-fetching');
       }
    });
  }
  this.el.on('click', 'button', this.fetchPhotos);
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var paris = new Tour($('#paris'));
  var london = new Tour($('#london '));
});
```

console log output in success function = true

Above code snippet is from tutorial. I have 2 queries related to 'this' object.

1. 'tour' &  'this' are same(as output suggests) but when i replace 'tour' with 'this' in data option of ajax call, it stops working. Why so?
2. Why arn't we using 'tour' inside other functions - error, beforeSend.etc.

Please somebody help.

Comment: this refers to different object inside success

Comment: Yes i understand this..inside ajax request value of 'this' changes thats why we use context. But why not we are using context - tour inside other methods..success, error..?? And why console output for "this===tour" gives true??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all had to do with the "context" keyword in the Ajax call.  Context tells it what "this" will be when one of the Ajax callbacks, such as success, are called.  In your case, you are passing 'tour' as the context, which means in your success function, 'this' is equal to 'tour'.

Comment: Okay..does it mean context definition is applicable for callbacks and that is the reason for data value we have to specify correct context that is 'tour'. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I understand it.  Maybe someone can offer up some additional info as well.